# In Lua, using a boolean variable from another script in the same project ends up with nill value error

Tags: lua, null, boolean, game-engine

This code is for a modding engine, **Unitale** base on **Unity** Written in ***Lua***

So I am trying to use a Boolean Variable in my script `poseur.lua`, so when certain conditions are met so I can pass it to the other script `encounter.lua`, where a engine Predefined functions is being uses to make actions happens base on the occurring moment.

I tried to read the engine documentation multiple times, follow the exact syntax of Lua's fonction like GetVar(), SetVar(), SetGobal(),GetGlobal(). 
Searching and google thing about the Language, post on the subreddit and Game Exchange and tried to solve it by myself for hours... I just can't do it and I can't understand why ?

I will show parts of my codes for each.

**poseur:**

```
    -- A basic monster script skeleton you can copy and modify for your own creations.

    comments = {"Smells like the work\rof an enemy stand.",
            "Nidhogg_Warrior is posing like his\rlife depends on it.", 
            "Nidhogg_Warrior's limbs shouldn't\rbe moving in this way."}
    commands = {"GREET", "JUMP", "FLIRT", "CRINGE"}

    EndDialougue = {" ! !  !","ouiii"}

    sprite = "poseur" --Always PNG. Extension is added automatically.

    name = "Nidhogg_Warrior"

    hp = 99
    atk = 1
    def = 1
    check = "The Nidhogg_Warrior is\rsearching for the Nidhogg"
    dialogbubble = "rightlarge" -- See documentation for what bubbles you have available.
    canspare = false
    cancheck = true
    GreetCounter = 5
    Berserk = false
```

**encounter:**

```
    -- A basic encounter script skeleton you can copy and modify for your own creations.

    encountertext = "Nidhogg_Warrior is\rrunning frantically" 
    nextwaves = {"bullettest_chaserorb"}
    wavetimer = 5.0
    arenasize = {155, 130}
    music = "musAncientGuardian"
    enemies = {"poseur"}
    require("Monsters.poseur")
    enemypositions = {{0, 0}}


    -- A custom list with attacks to choose from. 
    -- Actual selection happens in EnemyDialogueEnding(). 
    -- Put here in case you want to use it.
    possible_attacks = {"bullettest_bouncy", "bullettest_chaserorb", "bullettest_touhou"}

    function EncounterStarting()
        -- If you want to change the game state immediately, this is the place.
        Player.lv = 20
        Player.hp = 99
        Player.name = "Teemies"
     poseur.GetVar("Berserk")
    end
```

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my problem was to use `SetGobal()`, `GetGobal()`.

For some reasons my previous attempt to simply use `SetGobal()`Resulted in nil value despite writing it like that `SetGobal("Berserk",true)` gave me a nill value error, as soon as I launch the game.

But I still used them wrong. First I needed to put it `SetGobal()` at the end of the condition  instead of at the start of the the `poseur.lua` script because the change of value... for some reasons was being overwritten by it first installment.

And to test the variable in the function in my `encounter.lua`, I needed to write it like that

```
       function EnemyDialogueStarting()
            -- Good location for setting monster dialogue depending on how the battle is going.


        if GetGlobal("Jimmies") == true then
                TEEEST()
        end

    end
```

Also any tips an suggestions are still welcome !

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly, in lua simple values like bool and number are copied on assignment:

```
 global={}   
 a=2
 global.a=a--this is a copy
 a=4--this change won't affect value in table
 print(global.a)--2
 print(a)--4
```

Secondly,
SetGobal and the other mentioned functions are not part of lua language, they must be related to your engine. Probably, they use word 'Global' not as lua 'global' but in a sense defined by engine. 
Depending on the engine specifics these functions might as well do a deep copy of any variable they're given (or might as well not work with complicated objects).